# General solution for homogeneous differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

I have a differential equation

$$\frac{d^4y}{dx^4}+(ia-2\beta^2)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+(\beta^4-ia\beta^2)y=0$$

The characteristic equation is

$$r^4+(ia-2\beta^2)r^2+(\beta^4-ia\beta^2)=0$$

and the roots of the characteristic equation are

$$r_{1,2}=\pm\beta, r_{3,4}=\pm(\beta^2-ia)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

I know the fundamental solutions corresponding to $r_{1,2}$ are $C_1e^{\beta z}$ and  $C_2 e^{-\beta z}$. My question is what are the corresponding fundamental solutions for $r_{3,4}$? My concern or doubt is why all the books just give the general solution for the root of characteristic equation like $r=a\pm bi$ but not for $r=\pm(a \pm bi)^{\frac{1}{n}}$?

Thanks you for any advise in advance.

Comment: Compute the square root of $\beta^2-i\,a$: $\beta^2-i\,a=(u+i\,v)^2$.

Comment: Either as @JuliánAguirre says, or you could write the solution $C_3e^{(\beta^2-ia)^{1/2}x}+C_4e^{-(\beta^2-ia)^{1/2}x}$ if you want to keep it general for a while.

Comment: @mickep Thanks, you mean $r_{3,4}$ can also be regraded as _real_ root here? But for example if considering $r=a+bi$ as a real root, one could write the solution as $Ce^{(a+bi)x}=Ce^{ax}(\cos bx+ i \sin bx)$, which is not the classic solution for a complex root, i.e. $e^{ax}(C \cos bx +D \sin bx)$. What is wrong with me? Could the constant $C$ be a complex?